# Parallel search task allocation to threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an array of sorted numbers and I have to find a number in it with help of four threads. each thread can handle maximum of 100 numbers.

I have done it but

The problem is if I have 500 numbers. then I could allocate the last 100 numbers to thread 1 when completed. But I think this is not the best approach, as last 100 numbers should be allocated to any thread which finishes first. I should have a method to assign next 100 numbers to whoever thread completes and on n on.

Edit : I'm using binary search.

So, how should I do it ?
 Many thanks.

Comment: Use parallel stream like `IntStream.of(array).parallel().anyMatch(x -> x == number)`.

Comment: Side note:  I don't think its actually much of a speedup to parallelize searching a sorted array on numbers.  A binary search is going to be faster- if you break it into batches of 100 only 1 of those batches has the number.  The rest are doing nothing.  Its a minimal speedup at best-  log_2(num_worker_threads) comparissons.  Now if you have unsorted numbers you can get a speedup by sorting them, and you can do that in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that allocates 100 numbers then create a variable `boolean isLastThreadStarted = false` or `AtomicBoolean isLastThreadStarted = false` and in all 4 threads add this right before the thread ends :-

```
if(!isLastTheadStarted)
{
  isLastTheadStarted = true
  allocate100();  // your method that allocates 100 numbers
}
```

so the 1st thread that completes would set it to true and run the allocation.

Note:- declare isLastThreadStarted as a global variable so that it can be accessed by all four of your threads.

Comment: @MIK it depends on the OS but yes, you are right it is better that way, edited my answer :)

Comment: By declaring that global, how would I be able to know which thread completed, because any of the threads could set it to false. So I won't  know which thread to allocate next 100.
Also how to start that thread to work again after allocation? as I can't start the same thread again..
Thanks

Comment: @RishavKumar by declaring it as a global variable it can be set to true by only 1 thread and the first one that sets it to true can run your task

Answer (score 0):

The general way to do this is:

On the main thread before starting the workers:

1)Break the task down into jobs.  Each job is represented by some object, that can tell it what set of data to work on (for example a reference to an array, a starting index into an array and an ending index for a search).

2)Create a Queue of jobs.  Use a threadsafe queue class.

3)Start all threads.

On each worker thread:

1)Remove the head from the queue

2)If there was no head, you're done. Exit the thread.

3)If there is a head, process the job

4)Goto 1.

Then you have N threads each processing jobs as quickly as they can with no synchronization needed.